# separate auth for firebase multiple sites

Tags: firebase, authentication

I am using firebase to host 3 different sites. The idea is to have 2 different admin sites that would be managed by 2 different admins. Is there a way I can make admin user to only access admin-site-1 and not admin-site-2?

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy multiple sites on firebase hosting (2 admins + 1 client), but keep in mind that since all sites belong to the same project, they will still connect to the same Firestore database and/or the same Authentication service. You won't have separate resources per site.

I would approach this requirement by using custom roles along with security rules to control admin access on each site. Look for Firebase CodeLab and YouTube channel, there is ton of content out there on how to code this.